Bottom brackets for 2022 Salsa Stormchaser
Let's say I want to build this bike from scratch: https://www.salsacycles.com/bikes/2021_stormchaser_frameset
What Bottom Brackets would you recommend today that fit other components?
I only understand this is 73mm BSA shell, but don't know what BBs would be recommended for gravel.

What crank are you looking to use? That will determine which BB will work.

Some clues might be found in the specs for the full bikes, e.g. here's the current model with GRX 810, and the one with SRAM Apex. They both spec the Race Face Ride crankset, which is an MTB crankset. Indeed, 73mm BB means mountain bike BB, but it also implies that the frame was designed for MTB chainlines.
Indeed, if you check the frame specs, the chainline for a singlespeed setup is 51mm, and 49mm for a geared setup. SRAM specs a 45mm chainline for its standard road 1x cranks and 47.5mm for its Wide cranks. Hence, the Stormchaser is set up for MTB chainlines.
As the other answer observed, what BB you need depends on what crank you want. And you can have any crank you want as long as it's an MTB crank.

As mentioned, the bottom bracket depends on the crank you choose. 73mm BSA is a bit the more rare situation for gravel bikes, so you'll be limited in your choices as most gravel cranks are designed for 68mm shells, you basically have two options:

For Shimano: any non-boost MTB crank. But there are not so many options if you want a chainring bigger than 40T (with Shimano, you'll need to in the CUES range for that, which is OK if you want an 11-speed single chainring, Shimano MTBs crankset don't go larger than 36T). GRX cranks won't work (no problem on the rear to use GRX though).
For SRAM, the new gravel cranks/BB with "wide" in the name are designed for 73mm bottom brackets, so no issue there.

